# Array of points to one point in middle

Tags: php

I got array of points:

```
array(
    array('x' => ...,'y' => ...), 
    array('x' => ...,'y' => ...) 
    ...
    )
```

What is the best way to make those points one, that is in "avarge" position? Is pairing and then pairing and then pairing... a good algorithm?

I would give myself -1 for this question, as it seems to be really easy, but I am working on project for more than 20 hours now, and my brain went off.

Hmm... is it as simple as counting avarge x and avarge y?

Comment: Do you want a simple average, or a weighted centrepoint using something like kmeans?

Comment: Simple avarge, but of all points, not pairs, because pairs won't count weight after pairing few times, or will it? Is it as simple as a loop that takes 2 points and creates one in between? I need it to generate heatmap, but need to group some points so it would have any sense, since every point is different pixel.

Comment: I of course could just `round(x / 100) * 100`, but that would align those points to grid, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to turn your computer off and go to sleep for a couple of good hours. Then wake up rested and ready for a new programming session. This solution in based on an assumption that those 20 hours you have assigned this project was without any proper breaks.

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, it will certainly help you get there by yourself. Don't underestimate the power of a nap.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this function I wrote to loop through all the elements of your multidimensional array and return their average after adding all of the elements together.

```
print_r(getAveragePoints(array(array('x' => 1,'y' => 3),array('x' => 2,'y' => 4))));

function getAveragePoints($arrays = array()) {
   if(!empty($arrays)) {
      $i=0;
      $x = 0;
      $y = 0;
      foreach($arrays as $array) {
        // this would take avg 
        $x += $array['x']; // x
        $y += $array['y'];   // y
        $i++;
      }
      $avgX = $x / $i; 
      $avgY = $y / $i;

      return array($avgX,$avgY);
   } else {
      return array(0,0);
   }
}
```

Comment: so it is simple avarge of all `x` and all `y` ... just as I thought... if noone will negate this in few minutes, I will accept this answer.

Comment: That is what I would do :) There is no reason anyone should negate this because it works properly :) Try it. You could actualy use PHP function to round the avg values to 2 decimals or something since right now it returns more than that, but works

Comment: The code is not a problem, I will write my own, the idea counts :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple average option:

```
$pointArray = array(
    array('x' => 1,'y' => 2), 
    array('x' => 2,'y' => 5),
    array('x' => 3,'y' => 3) ,
    array('x' => 4,'y' => 6) ,
    array('x' => 4,'y' => 5) ,
);

$valueCount = count($pointArray);
$midpoint = array_map(
    function($value) use($valueCount) {
        return $value / $valueCount;
    },
    array_reduce(
        $pointArray,
        function($summary, $value) {
            return array(
                'x' => $summary['x'] += $value['x'],
                'y' => $summary['y'] += $value['y']
            );
        },
        array('x' => 0, 'y' => 0)
    )
);

var_dump($midpoint);
```